# Why shift key is not working

Tags: key-bindings

I have below .vimrc key mapping:

```
nmap <C-S-j> :tabmove -1<cr>
nmap <C-S-k> :tabmove +1<cr>

nmap <C-j> gT
nmap <C-k> gt
```

Don't know why C-S-j|k is not working.

Comment: on most (or all ?) systems (g)vim cannot tell shifted-control-keys from unshifted apart.

Comment: Looks gvim do support shift while vim doesn't.